# CSS - Image wouldn't enlarge up to its original size

Tags: html, css, width

A very simple problem but I'm not able to find a solution by myself...

Just an image in a blank HTML page and a CSS class that has a max-width set to 100% to help scaling this image when scaling the browser window.

The problem is when the window's width exceed the image's width, the image wouldn't grow anymore...

In my mind the 100% set on max-width is 100% of the parent right ?? Not the image itself ?

Link to Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gr7u1ytq/2/

```css
.image {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img class="image" src="https://preview.ibb.co/iNVyTd/Graph_Monthly_Expenses_1270.png" />
</center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-width` will only let the image grow as big as the image pixel dimensions. Your image is naturally 640px wide.

If you do this...

```
.image {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then the image grows 100% of the window.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/gr7u1ytq/3/

Answer (score 2):

Set image width 100% also

```
.image {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I don't know why I haven't test that before posting... If we set the width, do we have to keep the max-width ? It seems useless no ?

Comment: No, you don't need to set max-width in this case.

Answer (score -1):

**You do not need to give a particular class to img tag, just use below CSS for general images.**

```
img 
{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

after using the above code image will never cross the window size,

Comment: Yes I know, it's because I have simplify at most my code to be more focus on the problem and not on other CSS property that wouldn't have any effect here.
But max-width alone don't do the trick, it's width we need as stated by previous answer